# Use of Different .Net Languages?

Tags: .net, statistics, programming-languages, clr

Is there a breakdown of the popularity of the different [.Net languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_.NET_Languages) available?  Does anyone know of any surveys that give this information, or even if it is possible to determine this?

**Update**

The answer is **not** a list of the different .Net languages.  I would like to see statistics showing the relative usage/popularity of each .Net language.  Thanks.

Comment: You mean the popularity?

Comment: Reis, exactly what I am after - I have edited question to make this clear.  Thanks.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it isn't really a question about programming; rather, it is concerned with usage statistics of programming languages. Interesting information, to be sure, but not especially relevant to SO's scope. In short, the "problem" here is not solved with programming.

Answer (score 4):

If you assume Stackoverflow is equal and fair which I do, then just take a look at the [Tags](https://stackoverflow.com/tags) page.

C#     - 34912 questions as of 08/21/09 9:30 AM EST

VB.NET - 3770 as of 08/21/09 9:30 AM EST

C# is by far more popular on Stackoverflow, and I believe overall the most commonly used .NET language.

Here is a survey of the [overall most popular programming languages](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/index.html).  The definition of how it is calculated is found [here](http://www.tiobe.com/index.php/content/paperinfo/tpci/tpci_definition.htm).  This seems like a flawed way of judging it since it does not break out VB.NET from Visual Basic.

Comment: David, Excellent point!  Could give a breakdown of serious developers working in each language. Thanks. +1

Comment: David, C# is, in my personal experience, the most popular .Net language, but I do recall a podcast from last year (Hansleminutes?) where a MS employee revealed that the VB.Net favour of the Visual Studio 2005 Express was by far the most downloaded version. I'm not sure how this can be reconciled to the various surveys and the Stack Overflow statistics...

Comment: I like how that survey site looks at trends over the past several years. Very interesting read.

Comment: I would suggest that SO is probably tilted slight to .NET, given its founders, what it's written in, etc... VB also include VB6 which was pretty popular.

Comment: This data doesn't tell you about the popularity. It could easily be explained by the fact that, say, C#'s documentation is 10x worse than VB.NET, C# is 10x as complicated, VB.NET developers use different forums than SO and a dozen other things. According to some recent Channel 9 interviews, C# and VB.NET account for pretty close to 100% of all projects, with VB.NET slightly ahead of C# (yeah, surprised me too).

Answer (score 2):

Noe sure about surveys, but this list gives you all the .NET languages:

http://dotnetpowered.com/languages.aspx

They also publish their souces, so there are some useful links at the foot as well that might help.

Comment: Sorry, James, I'm not interested in a list of the different languages (already given in the link in the question), but in statistics showing the % usage of each language.

Comment: That list doesn't contain C#Builder so it's not complete. ;-) C#Builder is from Embarcadero, formerly Codegear, formerly Borland.

Answer (score 1):

Do you know about http://www.hotskills.net ?

You wont find them all there though...

Comment: Ries, not quite, though interesting reading.  How many employers are going to be looking for the more obscure languages (i.e Cobol.Net or A#), or even know what they are?  +1 for the link.